# Meteor package not loading

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I've added some packages to my meteor application but it seems that, from time to time, some packages wont load. In this case, crypto-sha1. This is the smart.json file:

```
{
  "packages": {
    "accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown": {},
    "underscore-string-latest": {},
    "iron-router": {},
    "iron-router-progress": {},
    "streams": {},
    "holder": {},
    "font-awesome": {},
    "collection-api": {},
    "filepicker": {},
    "fancybox": {},
    "jquery-ui": {},
    "jquery-ui-sortable": {},
    "jquery-ui-bootstrap": {},
    "moment": {},
    "fullcalendar": {},
    "bootboxjs": {},
    "crypto-base": {},
    "crypto-sha1": {},
    "crypto-md5": {},
    "dropbox": {}
  }
}
```

But during boot the only loaded packages are `crypto-base` and `crypto-md5`. Any clue?

Comment: 1) How does your `./meteor/packages` file look like? 2) Do you run the app with `meteor` or `mrt`? Did you try `mrt install`? 3) Are you sure the functionality of the `crypto-sha1` is not loaded? Perhaps it's only a dependency of another package?

Comment: Thanks @HubertOG 
1) seems to be ok, I mean, the link to the packages is there
2) tried both, same result. mrt install done, no effect
3) CryptoJS object should have the SHA1 and HmacSHA1, and it doesn't

I've also verified tracing the bundler.js file and it looks like they are nor crypto-sha1 nor crypto-hmac not among the select packages.

Comment: It's happening again. This time is with a fork I've made from the     xml2js meteor package. I'm adding this: "xml2js": { "git": "https://github.com/bitIO/meteor-xml2js" } to the smart.json and it's been skipped (not in the .meteor/local/build folder - nor it's children)

Comment: @bitIO after you add it to smart.json, you also need to run `meteor add xml2js` to register it with meteor at .meteor/packages

Comment: @imslavko I've tried all the possible paths. It happens even adding only with `mrt add`. In fact, that's the way the first time happens. It keeps happening to me from time to time but I still cannot determine the steps to reproduce :-(

Comment: if you ever get a stable reproduction going, it would be very helpful if you filed an issue on GitHub with reproduction attached.

Comment: Sure I'll do ... once that happens :-P BTW, great job with your meteor-tern